# What does "get on" mean in this sentence from Walden?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, phrasal-verbs, nineteenth-century-english

In the first chapter of [Walden](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/205), Thoreau writes:

> I cannot but perceive
> that this so-called rich and refined life is a thing jumped at, and I do not **get on
> in** the enjoyment of the fine arts which adorn it, my attention being wholly occupied with the jump; for I remember that the greatest genuine leap, due to
> human muscles alone, on record, is that of certain wandering Arabs, who are
> said to have cleared twenty-five feet on level ground.

[Having done some research](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_on), I read it:

> I cannot but perceive that this so-called rich and refined life is a thing accepted enthusiastically, and I do not **relate** well to the enjoyment of the fine arts which adorn it, my attention being wholly occupied with the jump;[...]

or

> I cannot but perceive that this so-called rich and refined life is a thing jumped at, and I do not **have a positive attitude** to the enjoyment of the fine arts which adorn it, my attention being wholly occupied with the jump; for I remember that the greatest genuine leap, due to human muscles alone, on record, is that of certain wandering Arabs, who are said to have cleared twenty-five feet on level ground.

I'm not sure if I paraphrased it correctly. What does *get on* mean in this passage?

Comment: How did you deduce the meaning of 'relate' from an article that among its many definitions doesn't seem to include that one?

Comment: @Joachim I did not. From the many definitions *To have a good relationship; to get along.* seems to be the closest, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'in' you boldfaced in your quotation is part of the "enjoyment [..]". Paraphrased, it could be "*in the enjoyment of the fine arts I do not get on*". I'm just pointing this out for thoroughness' sake.

From [that same Wiktionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_on) you linked, the following seem to be more likely candidates for interpretation:

> 2. To handle, cope or manage (over time); to perform or make progress.
> 6. To have a good relationship; to get along.

I believe the meaning lies somewhere in-between these definitions. Thoreau expresses his sceptical view of the popularity of "*this so-called rich and refined life [and] the fine arts which adorn it*". He seems to point out how he cannot "handle", or follow, "get along with", or, simply, *understand* that "*enjoyment of the fine arts*".

Answer (score 2):

'I do not get on in…' various things might work but  '… the enjoyment of the fine arts which adorn it' is too much.

'I do not get on in comprehension/English/writing…' might work.

'I do not get on in the enjoyment of the fine arts which adorn it…' is too great a leap and as such, indicates neither clarity nor precision, but simply confusion or pretension.

Comment: Isn't he saying the pretension of it is a leap for him? Haha, he made the jump.

Comment: He might be, but what could 'the pretension of it is a leap for him' actually mean? Can you paraphrase that in several ways?